# How can I combine values from one column into one row?

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables:

table 1 (let it be *'products'*):

```
----------------
| id | product |
----------------
|  1 | Apple   |
|  2 | Grape   |
|  3 | Orange  |
```

table 2 (let it be *'tags'*):

```
------------------------------
| id | product_id |    tag   |
------------------------------
|  1 |     1      |    tag1  |
|  2 |     1      |    tag2  |
|  3 |     2      |    tag2  |
|  4 |     2      |    tag3  |
|  5 |     3      |    tag4  |
```

I want to make a request to **SQLite** database which will generate such table as result:

```
---------------------------
|   product  |    tags    |
---------------------------
|    Apple   | tag1, tag2 |
|    Grape   | tag2, tag3 |
|    Orange  |    tag4    |
```

How can I achieve this? How can I combine tags into one column using only SQLite query language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is "group by" and "group_concat()":

```
select products.product,group_concat(tags.tag) from products join tags on tags.product_id = products.rowid group by tags.product_id;
```